# Blur not working as expected in IE when Focus is returned to sending element

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, internet-explorer

I am doing some JQuery validation where if validation fails I want to prevent the user moving away from the element with the validation problem (using `$(this).focus().select()`). As a bit of user feedback I also want to grey out the other input boxes using CSS. (i.e. all other input boxes are greyed out until the issue is fixed.)

This works fine in Chrome, but in IE it only greys out the *next* input, not all of them when I return focus to the original input. (If I remove the  `$(this).focus().select()` the styling works as expected, but the cursor is not "locked" to the input.)

How can I ensure consistency across the browsers?

The code I am using is:

```
$(".TimeEntry").blur(function(){
   if ($(this).val()){
      $('input').not(this).addClass('disabledClass');
      $(this).focus().select();
    } else {
      $('input').not(this).removeClass('disabledClass');
    }
});
```

(For demo purposes all my "validation" is doing is ensuring there is nothing in the input box. Any entry will fail the validation.)

See https://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/6g4rkcme/4/

Comment: Very good question, seems like a bug in `IE`.

Comment: This does work. However, no `css` is used this way - https://jsfiddle.net/6g4rkcme/7/

Comment: Thanks @RichardMauritz. I started off using attr('disabled') but that caused another issue in that it was causing issues with Tabbing / Entering to move between inputs: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43501430/how-can-i-make-tab-and-enter-behave-the-same-in-a-series-of-inputs

Comment: What about: http://jsfiddle.net/6g4rkcme/10/ Tab still works than when `input` is empty again.

Comment: Tried that, too. Trouble is my validation is actually more complex - it has to allow for multiple character input, and I don't want it to fire until the user submits. However... maybe I can try by testing for Tab /  Enter on keyup

Comment: Isn't `focusout` not an solution for that? http://jsfiddle.net/6g4rkcme/10/

Comment: That does the same as blur() :-/

Comment: Think the best option may be to test for IE and on non-IE browsers use the CSS option, and on IE use the disable option and accept that the user will have to manually click back focus for the next cell after a correction

Comment: About `focusout` its not the same as `blur` http://api.jquery.com/focusout/. Here you have an code to check if the current browser is an `IE` browser: https://jsfiddle.net/1s1h0jvb/

Comment: Just because i like this question, and i want a way to figure out.. ill write some code for you in jsfiddle ;) When i finish ill post at as a comment, if accepted i post it as awnser. However, i dont have an awnser to the 'why IE is not working?'

Comment: Thanks very much @RichardMauritz - appreciate it!!

Comment: Here you go. Fixed the `tab` key aswell on IE. https://jsfiddle.net/Lg04mjms/

Comment: Perfect! Thanks very much for this! (Please post as answer and I will accept it.)

Comment: No problem, i was happy to help you. `IE` unfortunately has allways wierd bugs and allways need workarounds :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why its not working within the `IE` browser. I tested it different ways, however all failed. I think its a bug in `IE`.

You can write a workaround however. As discussed above, I created a fiddle for you. It does the same in the `IE` browser, only in a different way.

**See snippet below**

```js
$(".TimeEntry").focusout(function(){
   if ($(this).val()){
        // Workaround for IE
        if(MSIE() === 1) {
        // This fixes the `tab` key cant be pressed when disabled.
        $(document).keydown( function() {
          if($(this).val().length < 1) {
            // If length of value smaller than 1 (aka 0) then set disabled false. So the tab key will work again.
            $('input').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
          }
        });
        $('input').not(this).prop('disabled', true);
      } else {
        // For chrome, firefox etc.
        $('input').not(this).addClass('disabledClass');
      }
      
      // Works for all browsers.
      $(this).focus().select();
    } else {
        if(MSIE() === 1) {
        $('input').not(this).prop('disabled', false);
      } else {
        $('input').not(this).removeClass('disabledClass');
      }
    }
}); 

function MSIE() {
    if (navigator.appName == 'Microsoft Internet Explorer' ||  
  !!(navigator.userAgent.match(/Trident/) || 
  navigator.userAgent.match(/rv:11/)) || 
  (typeof $.browser !== "undefined" && $.browser.msie == 1)) {
    
    return 1;
    } else {
    return 0;
  }
}
```

```css
td {
  width: 100px;
  height: 70px;
}

body {
  font-family: arial;
}

.disabledClass {
  background-color: #eee;
  color: #ccc;
  border: 1px solid #ccc
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

#triangle-right {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 8px solid red;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb1" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb2" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb3" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb4" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb5" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb6" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb7" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb8" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
    <td>
      <input class="TimeEntry" id="tb9" style='width:50px' />
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

What I did, is just checking on what browser the user is visiting your website. If its `IE` make the `input` field `disabled`, instead of animating a disabled input field with `CSS`.

If user is visiting with any other browser, do it the way you already wrote yourself. Which works.

Comment: Thanks again @richardmauritz. If you're interested here's the final piece.
Validation was to enable user to enter time into a timesheet system in chunks of 6 minutes, in the format like 1h06m. User should be able to enter using decimal point in place of h. https://jsfiddle.net/bdgriffiths/1r7g5xjx/

Comment: btw - using your "tab" logic, or a variation, I was able to simplify down to using the disable method for both Chrome and IE, by clearing the disable attribute as soon as the user changes the text box entry. (Had to use a hidden check box to record whether the app was in "validation mode" or not.

Comment: Good to hear, i hope it all works in a proper way now :)